# Font in Latex (similar to document file - Calibri, Times New Roman)

Tags: fonts

How can I know what font is available in my Latex?

i am following the template provided [Template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/university-of-rochester-masters-slash-phd-thesis-template/bwkpcxzdysky)

I dont think this is the font setting in the template as shown below.

```
\urlstyle{same} % to make URL font style same


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[font=small,labelfont={bf,sf}, textfont={sf}, justification=centering]{caption}

\usepackage{helvet}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can print the current font by `\f@family` and font size by `\f@size`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

\noindent Font used here is: \makeatletter \f@family \makeatother \newline
{\sffamily Font used here is: \makeatletter \f@family \makeatother} 

\end{document}
```

if you are using linux, just print the fonts in command line itself by `pdffonts filename.pdf`

[image]

Comment: thanks. How can I change my fonts? I found mine is `Font used here is: cmrFont used here is: phv`. May I know what is the meaning of second line? Why first line and second line is different.

Comment: cmr is the fontcode of Computer Modern Roman, which is the default font of LaTeX and phv is Helvetica. Go through this link to know more about fonts https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Font_typefaces. You can change font, for example ```{\fontfamily{qcr}\selectfont
This text uses a different font typeface
}```

Comment: thanks. so `latex CMR` is same as `word document =? `?

Comment: Not sure, but i thinks `Latin Modern` font almost looks like cmr font.

Comment: thanks. i mean what font in word document similar to latex (either cmr or others)?
Because i want to create a diagram in document file and then save it as picture and paste in latex

Comment: then use Latin modern math in word and use cmr font in latex

Comment: do you mean `Latin modern math` in words document? I cannot find `Latin modern math`.

Comment: `times ` is an old package. You can use  `newtxtext `.