# How do I make a diagram in MS Office match the default LaTeX font?

Tags: fonts

Basically, I want to create a diagram with words in `Words Document` and then save it as picture and paste in my Overleaf `latex`

So, i want to match both font style for `words document` and `latex`.

I know my latex font type is  `(Computer Modern Roman (CMR)`.

Is CMR similar to which font style in Words documents?

Thanks.

Comment: Not exactly matched, but the font `Calibri` matches similar...

Comment: You're not bound to use the default Computer Modern.  The pair `newtxtext, newtxmath` is based on `TeX Gyre Termes`, a  `Times` clone.

Comment: You could also try to make a diagram with https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf or https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pstricks-base. Imho, this is the natural way and it is worth a try.

Comment: How is this question different from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/521539 ?

Comment: With a modern TeX engine, such as LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you can load any font you could use in your word processor, including Times New Roman or Calibri. `\usepackage{fontspec}` and then `\setmainfont`.

Comment: If you are stuck using 8-bit legacy fonts, either `tgtermes` or `newtxtext` load a clone of Times.

Comment: @Davislor, thanks. I put `\usepackage{fontspec}`, but is not working. It said `the fontspec package requires either XeTeX`. I am using `Overleaf`.

Comment: @aan One of the options you can select on the left is your engine. Change it from pdflatex to LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

Comment: @Davislor, do you mean in `Overleaf`?

Comment: Or do it the other way around, use Computer Modern in Word (see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55/where-can-i-find-computer-modern-fonts-for-use-in-other-programs-e-g-adobe-ill)

Comment: @Marjin, thanks. I tried to download the installer file, unzip it. The folder name `cm-unicode-0.7.0`. Any idea how to install it into Words documents?

Comment: @aan To use Computer Modern Unicode, or Latin Modern, install the font (preferably for all users) and then select it as you would any other font.

Comment: @aan Yes, Overleaf puts the option to run PDFTeX/luatex/xetex on the left panel, IIRC. If you run an offline editor, the setting should be in a menu somewhere. TeXmaker puts it on a bar above.

Comment: @Davislor. Sorry, I still cannot find the left panel in Overleaf. I am using this https://www.overleaf.com/project

Comment: @aan In Overleaf, click the button with the Overleaf logo, which is at the upper left, and look for the Compiler setting.

Comment: @Davislor, thanks. Finally found `XeLaTeX`. However, i need to change all the setting for my citing/referencing when I compile using `XeLaTeX`. Need to find other ways.

Comment: @aan to install the font that you downloaded, you should open the folder, select all the font files at the same time (all the file names starting with `cmu`), right click on the list of selected files, press `Install`. If that does not work then there are a few other ways to install the font, but this is probably the easiest way.

Comment: @Marijn Note that, on Windows, there’s a difference between installing for yourself (in a hidden directory) or for all users (in the system directory).

Comment: @aan You don’t give enough information to solve that problem, but `\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}` and processing with `biber` might work.

Comment: @Davislor, thanks. I actually using `\usepackage[backend=biber, 
 style=authoryear-comp,
dashed=false,
maxcitenames=2,
maxbibnames=99,
uniquelist=false,
giveninits,
alldates=comp, 
dateabbrev=false, 
uniquename=init]{biblatex}`. I rewrite my question. What font type in Words is similar to font type Computer Modern Roman (CMR) in Latex?

Comment: @aan Ah, Either Computer Modern Unicode or Latin Modern Roman.

Comment: @Davislor. Thanks. i mean what font type in Words Document similar to Computer Modern Unicode?

Comment: @aan Both are free, OpenType fonts that you can download and use in Word.

Answer (score 3):

Both [Latin Modern](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern) Roman and [Computer Modern Unicode](https://cm-unicode.sourceforge.io/) Serif are free, OpenType forks of Computer Modern Roman.  You can download and use either one in a word processor.

You might need to install for all users, in the system directory, for the font to work in all applications.  If you install only for your own account, it goes into a hidden directory that not all programs check.

Comment: thanks. I am having problem to install Computer Modern Unicode in my laptop.  Will try select all the font files at the same time (all the file names starting with cmu), right click on the list of selected files, press Install

Comment: `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional (Times Roman font)` is another option

Comment: @aan If you want to use a font other than Computer Modern, loading `fontspec` allows you to use any font in LaTeX that you could in your word processor. I’d recommend this unless you are using one of the few publishers who still, in 2020, do not support LuaTeX or XeTeX.

Comment: @aan But you do have the option of seeing whether there is an OpenType or TrueType version of an 8-bit legacy font, such as Lingua Franca for Utopia.